# Multi-parameter match-finder with Redis

Tags: redis

I need to create an match-finder system for some data set, as follows:

There is a set of objects, each identified by a string `ObjectID`.

Each object has exactly N properties P<sub>i</sub>. Each property value is a string.

Database example for N = 3 (in real life N = 8).

```
ObjectID: P1     P2    P3
--------------------------------
APPLE:    RED    ROUND FRUIT
ORANGE:   ORANGE ROUND FRUIT
CARROT:   RED    LONG  VEGETABLE
```

The system must return sets of `ObjectID`s, matching given query on object properties. In query user must specify all property values. Alternatively, for some or all properties in query user may specify a "wildcard" `*`, meaning that any property value would match criteria.

Example queries:

```
P1  P2    P3        => Result
------------------------------------
*   ROUND FRUIT     => APPLE, ORANGE
RED LONG  VEGETABLE => CARROT
RED *     *         => CARROT, APPLE
```

All of this is trivially done with SQL.

The question is: is there a neat way to do that with Redis?

*Note that I'm interested in **Redis-based** solutions specifically, for self-education purposes; other DBs are offtopic for this particular question.*

*Update: Trivial solution with explicit `ObjectID` lists for each P<sub>i</sub> and application-side filtering does not look neat enough to me :-)*

Comment: This was a fun question to answer. I look forward to seeing if anyone else can come up with a better approach. I basically did "trivial explicit lists" but did the filtering on the Redis side ;). I hope that is neat enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is an inverted index.

For each column, have it map to a "set". Then, you can intersect the sets to get the result.

So, `APPLE:    RED    ROUND FRUIT` would map to the following inserts:

```
SADD p1:RED APPLE
SADD p2:ROUND APPLE
SADD p3:FRUIT APPLE
```

Then, let's say I want to query for `* ROUND FRUIT`, I would do:

```
SINTER p2:ROUND p3:FRUIT
```

This command is taking the intersection of the items in the `p2:ROUND` set and the `p3:FRUIT` set. This will return all the items that are `ROUND` and `FRUIT`, not caring what `p1` is.

Some other examples:

```
SMEMBERS p1:GREEN
SINTER p1:RED p2:ROUND p3:FRUIT
SUNION p1:RED p1:GREEN
```

---

My above answer is going to use some computation power because the intersection operation is `O(N*M)`. Here is a way of doing it that is more memory intensive, but will have faster retrieval because it effectively precomputes the indexes.

For each combination of properties, make a key that stores a set:

So, `APPLE: RED ROUND FRUIT` would map to the following inserts:

```
SADD RED:ROUND:FRUIT APPLE
SADD :ROUND:FRUIT APPLE
SADD RED::FRUIT APPLE
SADD RED:ROUND: APPLE
SADD RED:: APPLE
SADD :ROUND: APPLE
SADD ::FRUIT APPLE
SADD ::: APPLE
```

Then, to query, you simply access the respective key. For example, `* ROUND FRUIT` would simply be

```
SMEMBERS :ROUND:FRUIT
```

Obviously, this doesn't scale well at all in terms of memory when you have many dimensions, but it will be extremely snappy to retrieve results.