# Multi-parameter matching + weighted random pick in Redis

Tags: redis

Let's say I have a set of objects with properties:

```
Object Quantity Color  Shape   Kind
----------------------------------------
APPLE  12       RED    ROUND   FRUIT
APPLE  3        GREEN  ROUND   FRUIT
ORANGE 6        ORANGE ROUND   FRUIT
CARROT 0        RED    CONICAL VEGETABLE
RADISH 24       RED    ROUND   VEGETABLE
```

Object and all properties except quantity are represented as strings. Quantity is a number.

I must compose a random list of objects, based on user's query.

Query contains values for all string properties (that is, all properties except quantity).

Value in query may be either exact property value, or a wildcard (meaning "any value would do for this property"), or a negation — "NOT this exact property value".

Query result is an object, picked by weighted random from all object with matching properties. Weight for the random pick is the quantity.

For example:

```
Query                    -> Probabilities                    -> Example 
                                                                random result
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*      ROUND   FRUIT     -> APPLE 12 / APPLE 3 = APPLE 15    -> APPLE

!GREEN ROUND   FRUIT     -> APPLE 12 / ORANGE 6              -> ORANGE

RED    *       *         -> CARROT 0 / APPLE 12 / RADISH 24 
                          = APPLE 12 / RADISH 24             -> RADISH

RED    CONICAL VEGETABLE -> CARROT 0 
                          = (none)                           -> (none)
```

For self-education purposes, I would like to build this system using Redis for data storage.

The question is — how to do this elegantly and with least amount of application logic (as opposed to in-Redis operations)? Weights and negation kind of spoil the picture. Otherwise it would be [nicely doable with sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939365/multi-parameter-match-finder-with-redis).

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since redis can only query keys and not values, a good option is to store the individual values of each object in seperate redis lists.

For example, when you add the object ...

APPLE 12 RED ROUND FRUIT

you would store it as

hmset obj:1 name apple qty 12 color red shape round kind fruit

and then ...

sadd name:apple obj:1,

sadd color:red obj:1

sadd shape:round obj:1

This way you have a way to interrogate sets directly and be able to pick the object using a random number based on, for example, the total number of items in the set returned.

Hope that helps. If you need more explanation, hit me up.