# redis how to combine multiple commands in 1 query

Tags: redis, node-redis

**How to Query**

- red ferrari with limited edition
- with topSpeed between 200 To 210 And
- Price between 190 to 205

**DATA**

```
HMSET cars:1 make ferrari Price 199 limited yes color red topSpeed 202
HMSET cars:2 make porsche Price 555 limited no color yellow topSpeed 500

SADD make:ferrari 1
SADD color:red 1
SADD limited:yes 1
ZADD Price 199 1
ZADD topSpeed 202 1

SADD make:porsche 2
SADD color:yellow 2
SADD limited:no 2
ZADD Price 555 2
ZADD topSpeed 500 2
```

**I Tried** & Don't know how to add **multiple** range for **price** and **topSpeed** **both**?

```
multi.ZINTERSTORE('tempTom',4,
'color:red',
'make:ferrari',
'limited:yes',
'topSpeed'
);

multi.ZRANGEBYSCORE('tempTom' , 202 ,205) //range for topSpeed

//so how to add range for Price also ?
```

**Output**

```
[1,[]]
```

What am i doing wrong , how to query with multiple commands 1 after another ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK - This is pretty much impossible to do with 1 query in Redis. You are trying to use a key-vale store as a relational database. There is a way to do it in Redis but with 2 queries. However, you can wrap it as a single transaction in `MULTI / EXEC` and thus effectively making it 1 query.

For example:

Create 2 more sets, one for `topSpeed` and another for `price`. Then just perform a `SINTER` between those two (first query). Then use that result to query your `car` (second query).

Explanation:

```
# Inserting cars top speed
ZADD car:top-speed:210 "ferrari"
ZADD car:top-speed:300 "porsche"

# Inserting cars price (e.g. both cars have the same price)
ZADD car:price:190 "ferrari" "porsche"

# Using SINTER to get all cars with top speed of 210 and a price of 190
SINTER car:top-speed:210 car:price:300 // output "ferrari"
```

Use the output to query your `car` set and get all the other details (Don't forget the `MULTI / EXEC`).

You can add more 'filters' by simply adding more sets and performing the intersection on all of them. You would however, have to populate all these sets whenever you add a new car. But this is normal in Redis and does not suffer big performance issues. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7939473/5415018) for another similar example if my explanation is not clear.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***EVAL*** is what you are looking for? (perhaps not)..

It uses ***LUA scripts*** to execute a batch of commands in one call (and optionally return the result).
It is KIND OF like a stored procedure for REDIS.  The uploaded LUA gets cached so you don't need to load it over and over.

The examples I see aren't EXACTLY what you are looking for but demonstrate multi-part queries.  You need to read down into them to see the meat before you give up on EVAL (I *almost* did).

[Object Queries with Redis](https://blog.kettle.io/object-queries-with-redis/)

[A Speed Guide To Redis Lua Scripting](https://www.compose.com/articles/a-quick-guide-to-redis-lua-scripting)

**[EVAL (from the redis docs)](https://redis.io/commands/eval)**

The only reason I know about this is because a coworker here ***insists*** on using redis as a relational database.  It is not unlike using a hammer as a screwdriver.